# SQL Server error : [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]

Tags: html, sql-server

So basically my problem is I am trying to insert values in my SQL Server table `(maker_form_details)`, and I have no idea why I am getting this error.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
$sqlquery = "INSERT INTO maker_form_details(caseid,nom,address,date,no_de_tel,quest_no,lieu_interview,tom,mainbank,netscore,overallsatisfaction,q12_comment,q13_probablite,q14_comment,q15_recommendation,q16_sarisfaction,q17_temps,q19,q20Bancassurance,Mobhile_Banking,q21ameliorer) values ($id,'$Name','$address','$date',$tel,'$quest','$lieu','$tom','$mainbank',$netscore,$overallsatisfaction,'$question12','$question13','$question14',$question15,$question16,$question17,'$question19','$question20p1','$question20p2','$question21')";

$resultquery = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqlquery);

if(!$resultquery){
print_r(sqlsrv_errors());
}
```

The error is:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 102
>   [code] => 102 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]Incorrect syntax near ','. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
>   13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ','. ) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to avoid SQL Injection, you should use `Parameterized Queries`

```
$sqlquery = "INSERT INTO maker_form_details(caseid,nom,address,date,
         no_de_tel,quest_no,lieu_interview,tom,mainbank,netscore,
         overallsatisfaction,q12_comment,q13_probablite,q14_comment,q15_recommendation,
         q16_sarisfaction,q17_temps,q19,q20Bancassurance,Mobhile_Banking,
         q21ameliorer) 
         values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

$parameters = array($id,$Name,$address,$date,
                $tel,$quest,$lieu,$tom,$mainbank,$netscore,
                $overallsatisfaction,$question12,$question13,$question14,$question15,
                $question16,$question17,$question19,$question20p1,$question20p2,$question21);

$resultquery = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqlquery, $parameters);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-perform-parameterized-queries